# Modify FOR...DO to process files in descending order by size

Tags: windows, batch-file

This call to lame.exe works. The directory contains only mp3 and bat files:

for %%i in (*.mp3) do lame --scale 2 "%%i" "%%~ni_X.mp3"

I'd like to do the same starting with the largest mp3 file in the directory and finishing with the smallest. Only reason for this is I'm more patient when the longest tasks run first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o-s *.mp3') do ....
```

Perform a directory scan in basic form (`/b`) with no subdirectorynames (`/a-d`) in reverse order of size (`/o-s`) and assign each resultant filename in order to `%%i`.

Comment: Oops. After accepting answer I found it fails on file names containing spaces. I didn't specify that condition and can live with it, so my 'accept' stands. Others may consider this a bug.